# How to get List of IP address inside the LAN connection ( Host name + Ip address) in Java?

Tags: java, ip, router, dhcp

How to get List of IP address inside the LAN connection ( Host name + Ip address) in Java ?

need help for the example code.

Comment: Smells like homework. Didn't you find anything helpful on this site that already answers your question?

Comment: @bot kinda i am new at java networking things :)

Comment: Are you knew to searching content on a site as well?

Comment: @bot No sir i just newbie here please guide me :) 
some hard code syntax make me confused

Comment: check this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47719017/how-can-i-get-available-local-networks-lan-in-my-host-using-java/47722696#47722696) maybe is helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the following code in your application.

```
Process process = Runtime.getRunTime().execute("net view");
InputStream in=process.getInputStream();
```

Read all the lines from this input stream and you will get the list of host names in current LAN or WiFi network.